# pthread_attr_t default attributes - Official documentation

Tags: pthreads

I'm looking for the official documentation where i can find the default values of the pthread_attr_t struct.

So far i found [this](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node30.html), but it is not an official document.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pthreads being specified by POSIX, the most official documentation available is to be found in [the POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).  As far as I can determine, however, POSIX does not explicitly define default values for most pthread attributes.  The exception is `detachstate`, but even this is not specified explicitly: it has to be gleaned by inference from other documented pthreads behaviors.

Overall, then, you need to rely on the documentation, if any, of your implementation.

On the other hand, if there is a pthread attribute supported by your implementation whose value you care about, then I urge you to set it explicitly, without regard to whether the wanted value is the default for that attribute.  This is clearer, more robust, and more portable.

Comment: Hello @JohnBollinger than you very much for your answer and for your suggestions.